# Can we have verified Salesforce employees?

Tags: feature-request

Oftentimes I see people answer questions and they say that they are a Salesforce employee so they are sharing some internal knowledge or deeper understanding that would not be made clear in the documentation that's currently available. I don't doubt that a majority of these users *do* work for Salesforce, but would it be possible to add some sort of flair to these users to recognize them as "Salesforce Employee"s or "Salesforce Internal Development Team"?

An example I just ran across: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/321679/63090

The user that answered, sfcbweb, states that they work for Salesforce, but as a new user with no post history, how do we know that what they're saying is accurate? Some sort of signifier would give more trust in their answers.

Comment: I don't _think_ there is any way to flair users. (I also find this frustrating, and my internal guide for Salesforce employees asks that employees consider explicitly identifying themselves).

Comment: If there is ever a situation where we have reason to suspect that someone is masquerading as an insider, please flag them to my attention and I can reach out internally to confirm their status. I wish we had a better experience, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Like I said, I don't have a reason to suspect someone is impersonating someone internal, but I will bring it to your attention if I do see something.

Comment: Being an employee myself, I don’t see a need of explicitly mentioning this within the answers I provide. My profile mentions it, and contains a link to my LinkedIn profile. None of these are of course a solid proof, but it at least provides some better verification possibilities. I doubt there is a way of officially verifying it. Trailblazer profile can have a “relationship to Salesforce”-field set to Employee, but this does not require any validation.