# Should we encourage Salesforce employees to call out that fact in their profile?

Tags: discussion

Somewhat similar in scope as [Can we have verified Salesforce employees?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/can-we-have-verified-salesforce-employees) though that was asking for community-assignable flair (which Stackexchange doesn't offer at time of writing).

I came across [this post on Einstien Activity Capture](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/373192/24889) in one of the review queues, and the tone of writing suggests to me that this is a Salesforce employee.

Even with that context (if they are an employee) I don't think the answer is salvagable, but I think it would be helpful if SFDC employees self-identified as such in their profile.

Is this something we want to encourage?

Answer (score 4):

I have an internal guide for Salesforce employees that does encourage employees to self-identify in either their profile or their posts (or both) when they are speaking from an internal perspective.

It's a really big company, though, and not everyone who runs across SFSE knows about the broader scope of our participation here.

I support kind comments asking folks to identify themselves explicitly where they appear to be participating from an internal perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mind that SF employees fly under the radar on here. I'd prefer not to hinder the free-flow of correct answers from folks who can actually source them from the mothership. I know of a few and appreciate their regular contributions.

I suppose the assumption is that if they're a SF employee, they have the correct answers.  We all know that's not always the case, otherwise SFSE wouldn't be as important to the community.